# What design pattern would be recommended for this aproach?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am designing an application, and one feature I want for my app is that:

- Whenever a post gets 2 times more dislikes than likes, it gets automatically deleted and send to the submitter a message.

I am thinking about the observer pattern, is it a good choice?

Comment: Any design pattern could be a good choice based on one feature of an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Observer Pattern would be a good start:

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
>   called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to
>   implement distributed event handling systems.

In your example, the "Submitter" would be the Observer.  When they submit the post, they would subscribe to the "Delete" event.  When the post is deleted, the Delete Event will be fired and "Submitter" will receive it.